# Stuck with onblur event in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, onclick, onblur

[image]

When any text entered in text field, ( shown in an image )and if it is incorrect then it Open one alert box on ONBLUR event. It working fine in all browser except one, IE 8.

In IE 8 when I am typing wrong letters and then directly clicking on datepicker icon then it's not appear alert. That means not executes onblur event in ie8.

**NOTE**: Here text field has type text, so user can write anything.

Means I am facing problem in onblur event in ie8 any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work in IE7 and up. Just a thought.

```
<input type='text' id="id" name="name" maxlength="10" />
<input type='text' id="id2" name="name2" onBlur="Count(this);" maxlength="10" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function Count(arg) {
    arg.value = 'blue';
    return arg.value;
  }

// another option
  var t = document.getElementById("id");
  t.onblur = function() { alert("blurring"); };
</script>
```